# Question about tensor product between four-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to multiply together some 4 dimensional arrays (block matrices) in the following way:
[image]

where C has shape `(50,50,12,6)`, Q has shape `(50,50,12,12)`, R has shape `(50,50,6,6)`,

I wonder how I should choose the correct axes to carry out tensor products? I tried doing matrix product in the following way:

```
H = np.tensordot(C_block.T,Q_block) @ C_block
```

But a value error is returned:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2976/3668270968.py in <module>
----> 1 H = np.tensordot(C_block.T,Q_block) @ C_block

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (6,12,12,12)->(6,12,newaxis,newaxis) (50,50,12,6)->(50,50,newaxis,newaxis)  and requested shape (12,6)
```

Comment: `tensordot` reduces the arrays to something that a single `dot` can handle - with reshape and transpose.  It has the same problem as `dot` with regard to batches.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sizes of your arrays, it looks like you are trying to do a regular matrix multiply on 50x50 arrays of matrices.

```
CT = np.swapaxes(C, 2, 3)
H = CT @ Q @ C + R
```

The documentation for `np.matmul` (which can be written using the operator `@`) specifically mentions this case.

Comment: That makes sense! However, when I ran the code, I got a memory error: `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.09 TiB for an array with shape (50, 50, 6, 50, 50, 50, 50, 6) and data type float64`

Comment: @RandyChen, why did you accept this - given the memory error and shape?

Comment: clicked the wrong button!

Comment: I goofed.  You don't want np.dot.  `np.matmul` is precisely what you want.  Fixed original.

Answer (score 1):

Creating some arrays of the right shape mix - with 10 instead of 50 for the batch  dimensions.  That is, treating the first 2 dimensions as batch that is repeated across all arrays including the result.

The sum-of-products dimension is size 12, right and left for `Q`.

This is most easily expressed with `einsum`.

```
In [71]: N=10; C=np.ones((N,N,12,6));  Q=np.ones((N,N,12,12)); R=np.ones((N,N,6,6))

In [73]: res = np.einsum('ijkl,ijkm,ijmn->ijln',C,Q,C)+R

In [74]: res.shape
Out[74]: (10, 10, 6, 6)
```

`dot` does not handle 'batches' right, hence the memory error in the other answer.  `np.matmul` does though.

```
In [75]: res1 = C.transpose(0,1,3,2)@Q@C + R

In [76]: res1.shape
Out[76]: (10, 10, 6, 6)
```

With all ones, the value test isn't very diagnostic, still:

```
In [77]: np.allclose(res,res1)
Out[77]: True
```

`matmul/@` treats the first 2 dimensions as 'batch', and does a `dot` on the last 2.  `C.T` in the equation should just swap the last 2 dimensions, not all.

Comment: I wished I had read your comments first!  I also noticed independently that I needed matmul rather than dot.